Good guy defeats bad guy in a virtual reality resembling Half-life
I am looking for a movie/TV movie or maybe an episode of a series.... I don't know when it's from, probably 1997-2006. Sorry that's the best I've got. My guess is it's in the sci-fi genre. All I remember from it is: a good guy and a bad guy. The good guy might be a cyborg or have an artificial heart; not sure...
The bad guy (I think) kidnaps this girl for some knowledge. I remember a scene in which he connects these little pumps to her forehead so she can control this computer or something. I remember there is a virtual reality aspect to it because there were these pods that have like three crystal looking sticks on each side of the head. They close down like a crab's legs and then glow white. Then the person enters this virtual reality or cyber space or something. The thing I remember the most is that the good guy defeats the bad guy in the virtual reality in a game that resembles "Half-Life" or some sort of a first-person shooter and a female voice computer tells the hero where to find the rocket launcher, I think.... that's it! Whoever solves this one is the best of... the best... hands down...

anything from here that rings a bell? : http://www.avclub.com/articles/the-future-wont-look-like-this-11-unintentionally,84348/

Found your movie in the pursuit of someone else's query over at the SciFi Stack Exchange. The movie in question is Max Knight: Ultra Spy.


Is it The Lawnmower Man? 
It's got the virtual reality, the white tube connected to the head, and the virtual battle between the good guy and bad guy. 


no its not it.... :(

Is this Virtuosity (1995) with Denzel Washington & Russell Crowe?
